# Winsock 'SOCKET_ADDRESS_LIST' equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, winsock, porting

I have a Windows program that I am currently trying to port to Linux that defines a variable of type SOCKET_ADDRESS_LIST and makes references to its iAddressCount and Address attributes. Is there an equivalent to this in Linux sockets that will provide me with the same or similar functionality?

Unfortunately, I cannot share the full code, however, the program works similarly to this:

```
SOCKET_ADDRESS_LIST *list = (SOCKET_ADDRESS_LIST*)buffer;

for(int i = 0; i < list->iAddressCount; i++) {
    ... list->Address[i] ...
}
```